# Convert HardwarePixelBuffer format into R8G8B8

Tags: c++, ogre3d

Is it possible to convert ogre3d hardware pixel buffer format from X8B8R8G8 into R8G8B8 ?

Comment: From the docs "... a hardware buffer is an area of memory with which you can do whatever you like;..."  So if you have the permissions you should be able to.

Comment: I will have to do a copy from the hardware pixel buffer, then do the manipulations, then copy the manipulated data into the hardware pixel buffer again, this is not efficient solution.

Comment: You said `Is it possible` not `efficient.` Maybe I don't understand the documentation, but `do whatever` sounds like you can just modify the buffer in place.

Comment: Modifying the pixels in place must not be the efficient way. But I am not an expert. I think you could better ask in the ogre3d forum, there are people with good knowledge about hardware buffers.